# Autolayout issues. Two overlapping elements. No overlap in iphone 5, perfect in 6 and 6 plus

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

Spent way too much time trying to figure this out. So the above image is how it is supposed to look and autolayout works fine with iphone 6 and 6 plus but i cant get it to touch/overlap for the iphone 5 (bottom image). Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: You have any code or is it all done in Interface Builder w/constraints?

Comment: its all done in interface builder w/constraints. im using swift.

Comment: the circles have aspect ratio constraints

Comment: okay i figured it out, resized the label and increased the width and added extra constraints. i appreciate your response tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes it can be happening because of priority of contrains. In your case probably the size contraints priority of the elements is greatter than the constrains that defines the space between then. Check this out, hope that helps.

Comment: yes that ended up being the issue. thanks for the response. heres an upvote and this can be the answer.